# Which comes first: Illness in the Ranks or Cathars' Crusade?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose I have an [Illness in the Ranks](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illness%20in%20the%20Ranks) out and my opponent has a [Cathars' Crusade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cathars%27%20Crusade) out. If 1/1 creature token comes into play under the opponent's control, does the token die due to the effects of Illness or does it get the counter first before Illness's effect activates?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will die.

Illness in the Ranks creates a continuous effect, which applies constantly. From the moment the token enters the battlefield, it has -1/-1. Cathars' Crusade, on the other hand, has a triggered ability, signified by the word "whenever" in its text. When the token enters the battlefield, that triggered ability goes on the stack. Before it can resolve and add a +1/+1 counter, the token dies. (Players get priority, so state-based actions are checked first, and since the token has zero toughness, it dies.)

Answer (score 0):

It will die but Cathars' Crusaides ability will still trigger.

A ruling on gatherer for [Illness in Ranks](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366354) has this to say:

> If an effect creates a creature token that normally has toughness 1,
>   it will enter the battlefield with toughness 0, be put into its
>   owner's graveyard as a state-based action, and then cease to exist.
>   Any abilities that trigger when a creature enters the battlefield or
>   dies will trigger.